# AJAX request results duplicated everytime result page is accessed

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I am building a webapp using jQuery Mobile and AJAX to pull out SQL from the server with the help of PHP.

The callback is fine as it's displaying the correct values that I want. The problem is every time the page is accessed, the same data is being appended into the list thereby creating duplicates.

This is the ajax query:

```
function getNews() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http:mylivesite/news_ajax.php?',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status) {
      $.each(data, function(i, item){
        var newNews = '<li>'+
        '<p>'+item.title+'</p>'+
        '<p>'+item.content+'</p>'+
        '</li>';
        $('#currentNews').append(newNews);  
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
  });
}
```

I have added `cache: false`, but the same result.  What have I missed?

Comment: This testcase isn't even syntactically valid. Show your real one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's what happens when you *[append](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/append)* stuff. Stuff gets *[appended](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/appended)*.

[Empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) the target element first if that's the semantics you need:

```
success: function(data, status) {
        $('#currentNews').empty(); // <-----------------
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            var newNews = '<li>'+
                                '<p>'+item.title+'</p>'+
                                '<p>'+item.content+'</p>'+
                               '</li>';
            $('#currentNews').append(newNews);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$('#currentNews').empty();` before making the request.

Answer (score 2):

Two areas to look into.

1. When you get news, clear out the current news items with `$('#currentNews').empty()` right away on the success callback.
2. Make sure you are not invoking the ajax call twice on accident. Are there any callback or pieces of code making this ajax call happen twice?

Comment: Sounds like his application is _designed_ to invoke the AJAX request multiple times, which is fine. Consider a timed "refresh" function, keeping the UI's state vaguely in sync with the server's.